# Runtime error in hackerrank even when there is no division in the entire code

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am solving the following question in a hackerrank contest:

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/moodys-analytics-2018-university-codesprint/challenges/meeting-profit-target

and my code is :

```
int main()
{

    double need,ap,ep;
    long nod;
    int noq;

    scanf("%d",&noq);

    for(int i=0;i<noq;i++)
    {
        need=0;
        scanf("%ld",&nod);

        for(int j=0;j<nod;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf",&ap);
            scanf("%lf",&ep);

            ep+=need;

            if(ap-ep<0)
            need+=ep-ap;

            else need=0;
        }

        if(need==0)
            printf("0\n");
        else printf("1\n");
    }

    return 1;
}
```

18 out of 20 test cases are showing runtime error. Please help me out figuring out why this is happening.

Comment: A runtime error? Which one? Or out of time failure, i.e. too inefficient code?

Comment: For me the link to the contest does not work. Could you double-check?

Comment: I notice that you ignore all scanf return values. Is it possible that you got the input formatting wrong?

Comment: `for(int j=0;j<nod...` but `nod` is `long` so `j` should also be `long`.

Comment: `main` should return `0` upon success.

Comment: Except for the issues reported above, I see no other issues in this code and following fixing, it should run OK.

Comment: @Yunnosch I believe the link is just not working for you and me (and for everybody else which doesn't have an account). Links with restrictions are a not so good idea. It would've been better to copy/paste the relevant text. Though, I enjoyed the XKCD cartoon... :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I dont know why the link is not working for you guys, it opens in my browser as well as in incognito too. @Yunnosch It showed just runtime error which got solved by returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main()` is generally supposed to return 0 to indicate the program ran successfully. Returning any other value signals a failure, and Hackerrank apparently reports that as a runtime error.